# LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square, matrices cant be solved

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a matrix with linalg.solve, but i always get the error LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square. where is my mistake?
Thanks for your help

Here is my code:

```
reaktionsgleichung=np.array([[3,1,0,0,0],[5,0,2,0,0],[3,0,0,-2,0],[9,-2,-1,0,-2]])

loesungsvektor=np.array([0,0,0,0,0])

np.linalg.solve(reaktionsgleichung, loesungsvektor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is a 4 by 5 matrix, which is not a square matrix.

According to the documentation of [numpy.linalg.solve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html):

> Computes the “exact” solution, x, of the well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.

It only works with a square matrix.

Consider [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) for non-square matrix

Comment: so i have to ad a row of zeros to my matrix "reaktionsgleichung"? but then its a singular matrix

Comment: you are trying to solve for five unknowns with four equations right? There are infinite number of solutions. So to get one solution you would either pick one of them using some metric (least square) or to add more constraint (make it full rank). Adding all zero is not a valid constraint as you said it would be singular in that case.